# Zooming out to 1% and beyond in a browser

Tags: zooming

Is it possible to zoom out beyond the default settings in any browser to very minimal scales? Internet explorer 8 seems to zoom out the furthest...

Has anyone attempted this and if so, what method/coding should I use?

Apologies for the lack of coding - once I have a direction I can update my question with code if appropriate.